# How to Access HBase after JUJU

Tags: juju

I have used the hbase charm with Juju to successfully deploy hbase, however I no idea how to access the instance of hbase now! Normally I would use the shell provided in the ../hbase/bin/ directory but I cannot find it. Any idea how I can access Hbase to insert data at this point?

Thanks!

Comment: I see looking at the hbase charm that it will not "successfully" deploy unless you have the correct and complete cluster deployed. Did you deploy ZooKeeper along side hbase and add the required relationships?

Comment: Yes the ZooKeeper and relationships are set up. It shows the IP that it is running from, but I have no idea how to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the machines directly using `juju ssh`:

`juju ssh hbase-master/0`

Assuming you called your service 'hbase-master' this will ssh you into that service allowing you to perform actions on that unit. There are some examples of this in action in the hbase readme.

As far as how to use the hbase charm, if the readme doesn't cover your questions, it's likely best to contact the author of the charm.

Comment: Do you know where the hbase deployment is located on the machine? In addition to my question; I would like to use Apache Phoenix with hbase and Phoenix requires that the .jar be in the ../hbase/lib/ directory.

Comment: @DouglasTober Once you have ssh'd into the machine you should be able to search for the jar. As for the compatibility with Apache Phoenix, I haven't used either so your best bet is to get in contact with the charm author if there is an incompatibility.